# Par ordre chronologique

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

Je veux utiliser la phrase ci-après (pour un exposé, un résumé, etc.):

> Unités de recherche concernées **par ordre chronologique croissant**.

L'expression **par ordre chronologique croissant** est-elle un pléonasme ou non ?
Suffit-il d'écrire **par ordre chronologique** ?

Quelle est la bonne façon pour exprimer l'**ordre chronologique décroissant** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Même si ce n'en est pas un car la définition de *[**chronologique**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chronologique)* ne précise pas explicitement d'ordre, *chronologique croissant* ressemble quand même à un pléonasme. Il vaut donc mieux se limiter à *ordre chronologique* que tout le monde comprendra.

L'inverse peut s'appeler un *ordre **[antichronologique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/antichronologique)*** qui a dépassé *chronologique décroissant* depuis une dizaine d'années. 
[image]